# How is the quality of carbon wheelset from taiwan?

Tags: shimano, hub, wheels

Recently I read from some websites, it sells taiwanese carbon wheelset,
How is the quality of the carbon rim, spokes and hub from those wheelset made in taiwan ?
I didn't see any brand name, so it's blank name,

Spesification :
*Size       :700C full carbon wheels 20mm deep in clincher

type       : road bicycle wheelset

material : 100% carbon fiber

finish:     3k clear coating finish

cassete body:  shimano 8/9/10 speed or campagnolo 10/11 speed.

Hub      : Novatec hub A271SB/F372SB,sealed bearings,front 2,rear 4
               (black/red/white colors are available)

Nipple: aluminium (black/red/silver colors are available)

Spoke : mac aero 494 spoke from cnspoke from taiwan(black)

hole :Front 20H   Rear 24H, special hole also can be ordered

weight:  1430g +/- 30g each pair

including Skewers and brake pads*

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific?  There are _a lot_ of wheel manufacturers in Taiwan, and there is not one uniform quality between them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an unbranded wheel from Taiwan, it is one of 2 things:

- A quality wheel from a reputable brand being sold grey market.

or

- A quick and dirty design Made up so that somebody can make a fast buck on th Internet.

Given the quality of the hubs and spokes referenced, in this case, it is the second option.

I wouldn't buy those wheels. You will likely regret the purchase.